# How can I start Android app activity using Appium-Python?

Tags: python, android, appium

I want to launch an Android app with a particular activity. Appium has a `'start_activity'` function, but it's deprecated. Instead, it suggested using `'mobile: startActivity'` extension, but I can't understand how. I am new to coding and would really appreciate any help.

Googling and Appium documentation reading did not help.

Answer (score 0):

according to this [github issue](https://github.com/appium/python-client/issues/917), you can use something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, options=UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(capabilities))

driver.execute_script('mobile: startActivity',{'component': f'com.xiaomi.smarthome/.SmartHomeMainActivity',})
```

or according to the [documentation](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver?tab=readme-ov-file#mobile-startactivity)

```
driver.execute_script('mobile: startActivity', {'intent': 'com.xiaomi.smarthome/.SmartHomeMainActivity'})
```

both of them works for me